# Run CodedUI test to automate actions

Tags: c#, .net, coded-ui-tests

Is there a way of running CodedUI steps outside a test project?

I want to use them to automate some actions in an application.

Comment: Thats not the purpose of a testing framework. Please don't do that!

Comment: How would you automate MSAA actions then?

Comment: I really don't know. Maybe [workflows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692925.aspx). But that is a field a have only read about.

Comment: "Thats not the purpose of a testing framework. Please don't do that!" can you explain? Why is it wrong?

Comment: The same reason you don't use a saw to hammer a screw into a wall :p
This got off topic ... and 'should i use this or that?' and 'which software should i use' questions are off-topic on SO. If you have a specific question, you may create a new post.

Comment: Since you pointed out I shouldn't use CodedUI for this, I think you should at least provide some techincal reasons other than saw/hammer/screws. I know is off-topic, but your first statement was off-topic, too and I just replied to that statement.

Comment: If you are offended by my answer, I am sorry for that. I wanted to emphasize, that misusing a tools purpose is bad coding style. If it's okay for you and your colleagues don't care, do it.

Comment: Not offended at all. I was seriously open to your answer. Since you said it was not the right tool for this kind of problem, my question was genuine and I wanted to know your reasons. You just said it's not right but I wanted to know your motivations behind the statement.

Answer (score 2):

The program `mstest.exe` can be used to invoke Coded UI tests. Its `/test:{test name}`option allows a specific test (ie activity) to be executed, thus several different activities (ie tests) to be combined into one source file but only the desired activity is executed. Calling `mstest.exe` from a batch or Powershell script allows the activity to be executed without needing to type a long command each time.

If you already use Coded UI then there is no reason why it cannot be used for automating a series of GUI actions.

An example: For one project we needed to set a database from a backup before each series of tests. Manually that took 5 minutes and sometimes we did it wrong and so wasted time. With Coded UI it always worked and it ran quickly.

Comment: Potentially I could use a Process.Start to kick the automation from code, but it feels a bit "hacky" as the assemblies are already there and public. I found a solution (referencing loads of assemblies) I will write the anwser when I get a second.

Comment: The DLL containing the Coded UI test is not complete. It expects to have a whole test execution framework around it. The `mstest.exe` program provides that test execution framework. Also, there are numerous questions here and elsewhere about how to run Coded UI tests without Visual Studio, and how to run them from another program.

Comment: Yes, I had to include many references to public and private assemblies in the VS folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's a significant amount of overhead involved in coded ui that you may not need in your automation task.  To execute a coded ui test (and therefore run your automation), you'll need a full Visual Studio Professional or Test Controller/Test Agent installed on every machine that will be running the test/automation, and the machine will have to have a UI that is always available, I.E., a virtual machine configured so the desktop is always available and will not have interactions from another user.

Since your question was rather vague about *what* you want to automate, I can't really suggest anything in place of Coded UI, but it should be enough to say that you should use the tool that's best suited for the job at hand.  Sure, you *could* use it to run your automation, but why would you want to? (insert imagery of a Corvette pulling a camper here)

Comment: I found a way and it does not need the test agent/controller installed. I will write the answer when I get a chance. Is there any other overhead you were considering (apart from the test agent/controller installation)?