# Is it possible to use coded UI testing as just UI automation?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, automation, coded-ui-tests

Recently I have been doing a lot of coded UI testing in visual studio 2013.  And then I got to wondering:  Is it possible to write a coded UI test, not to test an application for stability/safety/proper behavior, but to just click through the Windows UI to perform a repetitive action?

I'm sure that there are other, less roundabout ways to automate actions on a Windows UI though, but I don't know where to start looking.  Can I get some suggestions on what to look up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run CodedUI test to automate actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30983896/run-codedui-test-to-automate-actions)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your Coded UI Scripts with MSTEST.exe. On top of that you can create console application to execute test cases directly with a simple click on Batch Trigger.

refer sample code for main method in console app below

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Playback.Initialize();
            CodedUITests.CodedUITTest test = new CodedUITests.CodedUITTest();
            test.Testmethod1();
            Playback.Cleanup();
        }
```

refer http://chamindac.blogspot.in/2014/03/execute-coded-ui-test-with-console.html for details.